# writing jQuery instead of $ to access controls in a page

Tags: jquery

Can I write `jQuery( "body" ).append('Hello')`  instead of `$( "body" ).append('Hello')` in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can write that way.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( "body" ).append('Hello');
```

[Read it here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)